# c++ undefined reference to '_JV_RegisterClasses'

Tags: c++, undefined-reference

I'm getting and undefined reference error to `_JV_RegisterClasses` for this code.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello world!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I really don't know what to do here. I can't even find anybody else with this problem. I'm using the [Code::Blocks](http://www.codeblocks.org/) IDE and have the `-Wl,--allow-multiple-definition` tag in my linker options.

Comment: Do you link with some static/shared libraries?

Comment: nope, nothing. Iv'e also reinstalled MinGw and Code::Blocks twice. At some point i did have SDL and SDFL, but not anymore.

Comment: Provide info about OS and gcc version. Also, does it still break without `-Wl,--allow-multiple-definition`?
`_JV_RegisterClasses` is normally a weak symbol, thus it can be undefined and it should still link. It looks like something is wrong with your `crtbegin.o` or `libstdc++.so`.

Comment: @whatsGravity You wrote you installed MinGw, so I guess you're on Windows.  Throw away such a minor IDE/compiler.  None of Visual Studio Express users has such a problem.  You can think about portability after you complete your 1st SDL project.  Perhaps you can entirely throw away the idea of using SDL and switch to [Unity](http://unity3d.com/learn) for your game development.

Comment: I did already get rid of SDL, i looked into unity, but i would really like a knowledge of c++, so i am trying to do that. I installed VS so i guess i'll use that now. EDIT: visual studio worked, so i guess i'm sticking with that. Thanks for the help!